# How to redirect $stdout?

Tags: ruby

What I've found so far is that i can redirect the stdout to e.g. StringIO like this:

```
@original_output = $stdout
@new_output = StringIO.new
$stdout = @new_output
```

But I also need a "callback" everytime there is smth. written to the new stream. It would be fine to subclass StringIO or whatever but I do not want to overwrite very method puts/print/...

Is there one method that I can overwrite, or how would I just get everything that is written to that IO?

Answer (score 2):

`method_missing` and message transmission seems like a path of least resistance (although others may have better suggestions)
e.g.

```
class FakeStdout 

  attr_reader :output

  def initialize(output=STDOUT) 
    @output= output
  end

  def some_callback
   @output.puts 'called'
   # logic
  end 

  def method_missing(method_name,*args,**kwargs,&block) 
     if @output.respond_to?(method_name) 
       some_callback
       @output.public_send(method_name,*args,**kwargs,&block) 
     else 
       super
     end 
  end 

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    @output.respond_to?(method_name, include_private) || super
  end
end
```

Then you can use as

```
$stdout = FakeStdout.new
# called
#=> #<FakeStdout:0x00007ffff4897500 @output=#<IO:<STDOUT>>>
'hello' 
# called
#=> "hello"
```

**Caveat:** Any method inside `FakeStdout` that would write to the output stream (e.g. `print`, `puts`, etc.) should call directly to the `@output` instance variable or you will end up with a `SystemStackError`